# Eonasdan Bootstrap datetimepicker format

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How to set a format in bootstrap 3 datetimepicker. I want the format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" and I dont want "AM" and "PM". For that in which language I can use here. The following fiddle How can I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
 
    format : "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",
    
});
```

```html
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format : "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm"});
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({format : "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm"});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<br/>
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
         <h6>datetimepicker2</h6>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why yours isn't working, using `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm` gives the output `We/04/yyyy 08:43`. If you want the output to be for example `01/03/2015 12:01` you need to set `format : "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm"`. For more information on format options take a look at the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) documentation.

See updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/656/)

You need to make sure that you include all of the necessary css and js files that the datetimepicker needs to work. You also need momentjs and jquery to load first. See code snippet.

Comment: This is not i am expecting. Here the output is "We/04/yyyy 08:43". But I want the output "01/04/2015 00:00" like this.

Comment: Ok you didn't state that in your question - the format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" gives you We/04/yyyy 08:43 - notice the upper vs lower case

Answer (score 6):

adding data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" in the input tag also works.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"/>
```