# How can I have content of child div pop out of the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div that shows status_div and a child div that has datePicker to view old logs, the problem is the content larger that pops up in child div like the datePicker gets cutout and doesnt shows properly.

```
<div id="status_div" v-show="showStatus" class="status_bg">
 <p v-html="statusMessage" id="status_update">
   {{ statusMessage }}
 </p>
 <div class="view_log_div">
  View Log: <datePicker></datePicker>
 </div>
</div>

<style>
 .status_bg {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y:auto;

  }

 .view_log_div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
</style>
```

How can I have content of child div pop out of the parent div ?

Comment: Upload a screenshot.

Comment: put overflow:visible on status div but if you want a more complete answer, you need to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Pete I have overflow set to auto.

Comment: how do we know that?

Comment: @Alex I cannot post screenshot however but what is happening is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29385490/3311276 when you hit run code and click calendar icon the calendar will be inside another div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `position:relative` on the parent div  like so

```
.status_bg {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
  }
 .view_log_div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: red;
  }
```